# dbt-snowflake metadata for row count

Tags: sql, metadata, dbt

currently I am working with the following setup:

- dbt-snowflake 1.5.2
- package: brooklyn-data/dbt_artifacts     version: 2.5.0

In earlier versions of dbt_artifacts (0.X.X) the file "artifacts" was parsed so the row_count of every model was set in a metdadata table. I upgraded a long time ago and the attribute "row_count" was obsolete for me, but now the need for it is coming back.

Is there any other package or macro how to create a table that contains the table and view name and row_counts of said model?

Thank you for every hep I can get :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other package or macro how to create a table that contains the table and view name and row_counts of said model?

Yes, you can create a table of row counts is to use the Snowflake metadata views:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_CATALOG AS database,
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS schema,
    TABLE_NAME AS table,
    ROW_COUNT AS row_count
FROM
    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES
```

Other way which I can see, you can use SQL macro:

```
{% macro get_row_count(table_name) %}
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS row_count
    FROM
        {{ table_name }}
{% endmacro %}
```

After that you can create a new model to generate the table of row counts like that:

```
models:
  - name: row_counts
    materialized: table
    columns:
      - name: table_name
        type: string
      - name: row_count
        type: integer
    select:
      - {{ ref('table_name') }} AS table_name
      - {{ get_row_count(ref('table_name')) }} AS row_count
```